# Is this openApi property "not required" or "required to not be there"?

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I am struggling to understand the meaning of the following snippet of an OpenApi v3.0.0 yaml file and can't find the answer in swagger docs.

I read the combination of the `not` and `required` keywords below to imply that for a `NotificationData` object the `Profile` property is not required to have an `instanceId`, i.e. it is optional. However `instanceId` is already optional in the definition of `Profile` so should be interpreted as not being allowed to be there instead.

Is `instanceId` optional in a `NotificationData`'s `Profile` or is it not allowed at all?

```
components:
  schemas:
    Profile:
      type: object
      required: [ fullStatus ]
      properties:
        instanceId:
          type: integer
        instanceName:
          type: string
        fullStatus:
          type: string
    NotificationData:
      type: object
      required: [ eventId ]
      properties:
        eventId:
          type: integer
        profile:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Profile'
            - not:
                required: [ instanceId ]
```